# Reverse An Array whats wrong with this type of code?

Tags: data-structures, arrays

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class reverseAnArray2
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        Scanner sc  = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size");
        int  n = sc.nextInt();
        int a [] = new int [n] ;
        int b [] = new int [n] ;
        System.out.println("Enter elements");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
        
            a[i]=sc.nextInt() ;
        }
        int size = n;
        System.out.println("Reverse array is : ");
        int p=0;
        while(n>=0 && p<n)
        {
            
            a[--n] = a[p] ;
            ++p;
        }
        for(int i =0;i<size;i++)
        {
             System.out.println(+ a[i]);
        }
       
        
}
}
```

The output comes correct but only up to the last $n/2$ terms, rest of it gets repeated. The output was correct when I used another fresh array to store data. But that's not an optimal code. I want to reverse it without using another array.

Comment: "Please spot the problems in my code" questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you increment $p$, whilst also decrementing $n$. Since your condition in the `while` loop is that `p < n`, then the while loop will only work for half the elements.

Also, note that you delete the last $n/2$ values, since you modify them without first reading them.